# ES6 - Destructuring assignment - Unpack some properties from existing object to a new object?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is it possible to unpack some of the keys of an object to a new object?

Let's say, I want to copy 3 of the keys (`a`, `b`, `c`) from `test` object to a new object (`abc`). Below mention code will work.

```
const test = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
const {a, b, c} = test;
const abc = { a, b, c, f: 6};
```

**Is there any approach with which I can do it in a single statement?**

There is one more approach.

```
const test = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
const abc = { ...test, f: 6};
```

But with this approach, I would later have to delete the unwanted keys (`d`, `e` in my case).

(Best Case Solution: If we don't have to keep track of unwanted keys. There can be n number of unwanted keys.)

Comment: Just write a [helper function](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck). Any reasonably named helper will likely be more readable than some super complicated destructure/restructure.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [object rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to destructure your initial object:

```js
const test = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
const {d, e, ...abc} = { ...test, f: 6};

console.log(abc);
```

Comment: This is specific to exclude keys d and e - I think the question is for any number of unknown keys?

Comment: The overhead would be huge if test contains are large number of keys, of which you only need three

Comment: @FabioLolli perhaps. Still, clever answer.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but I am looking for - any number of unknown keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the specific keys you're going to need in the new Object, I would use good old `Object.assign`

```
const extendInfo = { //object containing properties to extend other object  }
const abc = { //your obj to extend }
Object.assign(abc, { a: extendInfo.a, b: extendInfo.b, c: extendInfo.c });
```

If you have a lot of props to extract the syntax becomes heavier and I would suggest a different approach, but if it's just a couple props, I think this is the cleaner and faster approach - and technically one line if you don't count variable declarations

Answer (score 2):

Using destructuring the params and IIFE (Immediately invoked function expressions), we can get rid of the unwanted keys in the source objects.

```js
const test = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
const abc = (({a,b,c}) => ({a, b, c}))(test);
console.log(abc);
```

For ES5 compatibility,

```js
var test = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
    
var abc = (function (test) {
  return {
    a: test.a,
    b: test.b,
    c: test.c
  }
})(test);

console.log(abc);
```